# Can we add SSL to EC2 elastic IP without having any domain

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

**Scenario:** I have an EC2 instance which hosts the api's.
I am using elastic ip for ec2 instance.
This is the url where I can access to my apis.

```
ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I want to add ssl to this url

please guide how to add ssl to my ec2 instance

Comment: according to AWS i need to user the load ballancer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have ssl certificates for *.amazonaws.com, you need to have custom domain and for that domain you can have ssl certificate, basically for getting ssl certificates you need to have DNS control of that domain or your one of the emails should be listed in WHOIS lookup, both not possible for amazonaws.com

Comment: Thanks for the update - sounds like the correct answer - i've read the same answer somewhere else as well. can i get any source from aws regarding this information?